# Создание меню для мобильной версии сайта

Tags: html, css, css3

Хотел создать меню на мобильную версию сайта, где при нажатии на иконку "меню" разворачивался (и не закрывался до повторного нажатия на ту же иконку) список с дальнейшей навигацией. Слышал, что можно сделать это через CSS и HTML (checkbox вроде) (без JS). 
Прошу помочь разобраться с этим вопросом.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: В гугле `адаптивное выпадающее меню без js`.

Comment: [PureCSS Menu](http://codepen.io/jsndks/pen/xOGaPE)

Comment: http://builder.swimbi.com/  вот не хилое меню

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Для ПК прячем кнопку МЕНЮ (т.е до 767px - кнопка МЕНЮ будет скрыта)
2. Кнопка МЕНЮ будет появляться при меньшем разрешении - в данном примере от 767px
3. Делаем привязку кнопки МЕНЮ непосредственно с самим меню, для этого используем псевдокласс [checked](http://htmlbook.ru/css/checked) + используем [cелектор](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors) `~` (правые соседи: все `.list-menu` на том же уровне вложенности, которые идут после `label`), также вместо `~` можно использовать `+` (это более строгий вариант, который выберет первого правого соседа).
4. [Стилизацируем checkbox](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/)

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav{
  background: #222;  
  padding: 15px;
}
.list-menu{
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
.list-menu > li > a{
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
.list-menu > li > a:hover{
  background: #000;
}

#btn-menu{
  display: none;
}
#btn-menu + label{
  display: none; 
  position: relative;
  color: #fff; 
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#btn-menu + label:before{
  content: '\f0c9';  
  display: inline-block;
  font-family:'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 22px;
}
#btn-menu:checked + label:before{
  content: '\f00d';
  color: #f00;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 
   #btn-menu + label{
      display: inline-block;
   }
  #btn-menu + label + .list-menu{
    display: none;
  }
  #btn-menu:checked + label + .list-menu{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
  <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu" />
  <label for="btn-menu"></label>

  <ul class="list-menu">
    <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Видел такое... Спасибо, но всё же, я вот не понимаю принципа работы... Не могли бы объяснить?

Comment: @Андрей Добавил в ответ.

Comment: фонт грузить из-за одной фигни?))

Comment: @Jean-Claude - это все лишь пример

Comment: В старых браузерах плюсы между селекторами не покатят и :before :after туда же! используйте JS! С ним веселее)) анимацию можно сделать (плавное открытие) и тд. Что, у вас на сайте вообще не используется JS????